# Круговой слайдер из 5-и элементов

Tags: javascript, css3, анимация, css-animation, slider

Как реализовать анимацию кругового слайдера из 5-и элементов, похожего на тот, что на изображении ниже?

[image: Слайдер круговой]

На сколько градусов правильно повернуть `item`? Тут ведь не правильный пятиугольник нужен, а изображения должны идти перпендикулярно области наблюдения.

Вот начальная заготовка:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100% ;
}


.circularSlider_full {
  position: relative;
  width: 100% ;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 3;
}

.circularSlider {
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 390px;

  perspective: 1000px;
}

.circularSlider_content {
  width: 100% ;
  height: 390px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 10s infinite;
}

.circularSlider_item {
  width: 240px;
  height: 390px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% ;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;

}


.circularSlider_item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(180px);
}

.circularSlider_item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(72deg) translateZ(180px);
}

.circularSlider_item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(144deg) translateZ(180px);
}

.circularSlider_item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(216deg) translateZ(180px);
}

.circularSlider_item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateY(288deg) translateZ(180px);
}


@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(180px) rotateY(0deg);
  }

  12.5% {
    transform: translateZ(180px) rotateY(-72deg);
  }

  25% {
    transform: translateZ(180px) rotateY(-144deg);
  }

  37.5% {
    transform: translateZ(180px) rotateY(-216deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translateZ(180px) rotateY(-288deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateZ(180px) rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circularSlider_full">
  <div class="circularSlider">
    <div class="circularSlider_content">
      <div class="circularSlider_item">
        <img width="148" height="142" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlackStar1991/Pictures-for-sharing-/master/Chest/chest.svg" alt="chest">
      </div>
      <div class="circularSlider_item">
        <img width="148" height="142" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlackStar1991/Pictures-for-sharing-/master/Chest/chest.svg" alt="chest">
      </div>
      <div class="circularSlider_item">
        <img width="148" height="142" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlackStar1991/Pictures-for-sharing-/master/Chest/chest.svg" alt="chest">
      </div>
      <div class="circularSlider_item">
        <img width="148" height="142" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlackStar1991/Pictures-for-sharing-/master/Chest/chest.svg" alt="chest">
      </div>
      <div class="circularSlider_item">
        <img width="148" height="142" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlackStar1991/Pictures-for-sharing-/master/Chest/chest.svg" alt="chest">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Буду благодарен за объяснения относительно анимации.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил

Comment: О! Метка добавилась. Тогда вечерком гляну. А то на чистом CSS слишком громоздко, а если сокращать, используя новые фишки, то поддержка страдает.

Comment: да, там будет JS c переключалкой слайдов, и возможно, если получиться, с возможностью вращать перетаскиванием. Для начала понять как соблюдать перспективу и вращать что бы сундуки всегда смотрели на пользователя

Comment: чтобы перспектива сохранялась, прокидывайте её до нужных элементов, добавляя им `transform-style: preserve-3d;`. В вашем случае добавьте к `.circularSlider_item` - сундуки будут в контексте перспективы. Далее нужно повернуть каждый `<img>` в обратную сторону на нужный угол. Это делается или через JS или через CSS-переменные и `@property`.

Comment: Можете показать, а то пока непонятно, как его вертеть

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
class Slider {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node
    this.list = null
    this._counter = 0
    this.sides = 0
    this.step = 0
    this.shift = 0
    
    this.findParts()
    this.prepare()
    this.listen()
  }
  
  findParts() {
    this.list = this.node.querySelector('[data-slider-list]')
    this.items = [...this.list.children]
    this.step_buttons = [...this.node.querySelectorAll('[data-slider-step-button]')].map((button) => {
        return {
        node: button,
        value: !!button.dataset.sliderStepButton ? +button.dataset.sliderStepButton: 1
      }
    })
  }
  
  prepare() {
    this.sides = this.items.length
    this.step = 2 * Math.PI / this.sides
    this.shift = Math.PI / 2
    this.counter = 0
  }
  
  listen() {
    this.step_buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.node.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.counter = this.counter + button.value
      })
    })
  }
  
  listenKeys(e) {
    if(e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      this.counter = this.counter - 1
    } else if(e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
      this.counter = this.counter + 1
    }
  }
  
  notify() {
    this.items.forEach((item, i) => {
      const pos = (i + this.counter) * this.step + this.shift
      const cos = Math.cos(pos)
      const sin = Math.sin(pos)
      const scale = Math.max(0.3, (sin + 1) / 2)
      
      item.style.setProperty('--cos', cos)
      item.style.setProperty('--sin', sin)
      item.style.setProperty('--scale', scale)
    })
  }
  
  get counter() {
    return this._counter
  }
  
  set counter(new_value) {
    this._counter = new_value < 0 ? this.sides + new_value : new_value % this.sides
    this.notify()
  }
}

const slider = new Slider(document.querySelector('.slider'))
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: calc(100vw / 106);
  --radius-x: 30em;
  --radius-y: 10em;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__list {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider__list__item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background-image: url('https://market.games.mail.ru/s3/media/product/picture/2020/2/f88a19d82b0e76c6905b2b4afab42452.png');
  background-size: cover;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform: 
    translateX(calc(var(--cos) * var(--radius-x)))
    translateY(calc(var(--sin) * var(--radius-y)))
    scale(calc(var(--scale) * 2))
  ;
}

.slider__list__step-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: black;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider__list__step-button_prev {
  left: 0;
}

.slider__list__step-button_next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <button class="slider__list__step-button slider__list__step-button_prev" data-slider-step-button="-1">Назад</button>
  <ul class="slider__list" data-slider-list>
    <li class="slider__list__item"></li>
    <li class="slider__list__item"></li>
    <li class="slider__list__item"></li>
    <li class="slider__list__item"></li>
    <li class="slider__list__item"></li>
  </ul>
   <button class="slider__list__step-button slider__list__step-button_next" data-slider-step-button="1">Вперед</button>
</div>
```

Comment: только с зиндексом нужно что-то сделать но мне уже лень

Comment: Чет попробовал вставить в item пример изображений, и оно как не завелось. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackStar1991/dyrnukq3/1/ Или я где-то ошибаюсь, или оно не вертится

Comment: что не вертится?

Comment: При смещении ползунка исчезают элементы которые были в item и карусель пропадает

Comment: убрал ползунок чтобы не смущать

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы не использовать готовую библиотеку gsap, она не слишком обьемная и можно легко реализовать нужный слайдер без проблем, я с помощью неё реализовал подобный слайдер. По этому примеру ( https://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/KVmpOG )

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
var boxes = $(".box"),
    stage = $(".stage");

TweenLite.set(stage, {
  css: {
    perspective: 1100,
    transformStyle: "preserve-3d"
  }
});

boxes.each(function(index, element) {
  TweenLite.set(element, {
    css: {
      rotationY: index * 360 / 13,
      transformOrigin: "50% 50% -420"
    }
  });
  TweenMax.to(element, 20, {
    css: {
      z:0.01,
      rotationY: "+=359"
    },
    repeat: -1, // 20
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  });
});
  
});
```

Comment: Использование сторонних библиотек не подходит, поскольку слайдер планируется вешать на фреймворк